# AdvancedDataGrid: optimizing adding to the underlying dataProvider

Tags: apache-flex, advanceddatagrid

friends,

I know ADG related questions generally get ignored because "it's a crappy component". Indeed, it is not one of my favorite pieces of code ever, but I'm stuck with it and have been working (pretty hard) at optimizing its performance. Turns out there's a fair amount of stuff one can do to make things go fast. One thing I've been stuck on, though, is not to optimize adding an element to the underlying dataprovider. Say you want to add a row to the ADG using a addChildAt call on the DP. All seems well but the operation is so slow - it's unbearable. Now, I realize that the ADG may need to redraw all the stuff below the line added, but seriously, in 2011 that should not take a load of time and 100$ of my CPU. Does anyone know what may be the main culprit?

Note: I'm able to catch the CollectionEvent of kind "add" and not deliver them to the ADG, which I thought would do the trick, but the ADG still updates and takes forever to do so, so I'm guessing there's something else somewhere else.

thanks for any tips!

f

Answer (score 0):

ADG is the main culprit.  Abandon all hope, ye who use the AdvandedDataGrid...  Have you checked through it's source code? It's atrocious on sooo many levels....  Even if you find the culprit and come up with a fix, almost all real methods and properties are marked final and private, so that you simply can't override it's type of behavior.

It's a crappy answer, but I still stand behind it...